# Google Cloud Functions slow down after a while

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I use Google Cloud functions with node12. I run htmlparser2 in my code. When I deploy application, htmlparser2's execution speed is around 160ms. But after a while function execution speed increases to 5000ms. Do you have any idea?

index.js

```
const crawl = require('./crawl.js');

exports.helloWorld = async (req, res) => {
  const url = req.query.url;
  const result = await crawl(url);
  
  res.status(200).type('application/json').send(result);
};
```

crawl.js

```
const bookRecipe = require('./recipes/book');
const quotesRecipe = require('./recipes/quotes');

module.exports =  async (url) => {
  console.log('url', url);
  console.time('books');
  const result = await bookRecipe(url);
  console.timeEnd('books');

  console.time('quotes');
  const quotes = await quotesRecipe(result.quotesLink);
  console.timeEnd('quotes');

  result.quotes = quotes;

  return result;
}
```

recipes/book.js

```
module.exports =  async (url) => {
      const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * agents.length);  
      const agent = agents[random];
    
      console.time("books::fetch")
      const result = await fetch(url, {
        headers: agent
      });
      console.timeEnd("books::fetch");
      
      const text = await result.text();
      console.time('books::parser');
      const dom = htmlparser2.parseDocument(text);
      console.log('books::length', text.length);
      console.timeEnd('books::parser');
    
      console.time('books::cheerio');
      const $ = cheerio.load(dom);
      console.timeEnd('books::cheerio');
      ...
    }
```

Everything is almost same in logs. But htmlparser2's execution is too long in second logs.

Logs:

```
// normal
books::fetch: 305.897ms
books::length 523973
books::parser: 165.133ms // htmlparser2
books::cheerio: 0.547ms
books: 585.574ms

quotes::fetch: 979.455ms
quotes::length 314233
quotes::parser: 54.109ms // htmlparser2
quotes::cheerio: 0.127ms
quotes: 1118.580ms


//abnormal
books::fetch: 593.701ms
books::length 524032
books::parser: 5284.212ms // htmlparser2
books::cheerio: 0.147ms
books: 6210.373ms

quotes::fetch: 1913.821ms
quotes::length 312932
quotes::parser: 2685.719ms // htmlparser2
quotes::cheerio: 0.134ms
quotes: 4722.583ms
```

Comment: Can you share how did you build the function? I think you are performing processing in background.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere  I added code snippet.

Comment: How do you call this function? Can you explain/share the big picture?

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: When the parsing time increases does it stay high or it's just some executions that are slow? Does the memory usage of the function keep growing indefinitely? This may point out to a memory leak in the code/library. That said it is unlikely we are able to help debugging a +5 second time increase, which may not even be an issue at all but rather than the library sometimes takes more time for whatever reason (maybe the html content itself).

Comment: It isn't deterministic. I couldn't create now. But I know it will occur again :)